# How can I delete all items in a list from SharePoint2013?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have a list with over 1000 items. I want to delete these items from the list but a lot of the scripts and suggestions I've read have resulted in errors or null results. I don't want to delete the list just the items within it. I tried this script most recently, but it threw me some errors. I don't quite understand why it threw these errors however.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 

$site     =      new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://share-internal.MySite.com") # is a legit url
$relweburl = ”/teams/Location/Components/”
$web      =     $site.openweb($relweburl)

$list    =    $web.Lists["Testing Board"]                                                                       

$listItems = $list.Items
$listItemsTotal = $listItems.Count

for ($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{ 
 if($listItems[$x].name.Contains("3")) 
 { 
  Write-Host("DELETED: " + $listItems[$x].name)
  $listItems[$x].Delete()
 }  
}
```

I figured I'd post the errors below because if I'm missing some sort of Add-On that would make sense

```
new-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:3 char:18
+ ...      =      new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://share-inte ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:1
+ $web      =     $site.openweb($relweburl)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:7 char:1
+ $list    =    $web.Lists["Testing Board"]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: Please, could you specify the correct SharePoint version? In the title, you typed 2013 but the question is tagged with SharePoint Online. The second question, you are using Server Object Model in PowerShell to remove those items in the list, could you explain where will you run this script, I mean, in a farm server or remotely from any computer?

Comment: I want to run it remotely from any computer. I am not very well versed in using Powershell but outside of deleting the list itself a lot of the suggestions were powershell or using Flow/PowerApps which I am unable to utilize.

Answer (score 1):

I Ultimately was able to take some code from "Knowledge - Craft - Truthful 2017" I found using SharePoint PnPPowerShell for SharePoint 2013 proved to be simple and easy in installing the module and deploying a solution. I'll post the script below in case anyone in the future will find this Script or at least the Module used helpful.

Many Thanks for Jaloplo for his help. He sent links that help refine some of my searches which lead me to this solution ultimately.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "http://share-internal.company.com/subpage1/subpage2/subpage3"
# Put Core URL Above
# Put List Name Below (In both Lines of the script)
#Will it works at ~1 Item per Second the Rough Estimate is: Total Items / 60 
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "Testing List"

foreach ($Item in $items){
    try{
        Remove-PnPListItem -List "Testing List" -Identity $Item.Id -Force
        }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Error"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to accomplish what you need but using Server Side Object Model is not the right one. If you want to use PowerShell for doing it you should use CSOM (Client Side Object Model) to be able to execute it out the farm servers. The following [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539976(v%3doffice.14)) explains how to implement actions over lists with CSOM but in C# code. This can be a reference for adding, removing or changing items. This [link](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/bulk-delete-sharepoint-online-list-items-using-powershell.html) has an example of a PowerShell script that makes what you want to do.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: So in the Powershell example of the CSOM script. It attempts to Add-Type -Path for two dlls but I know I don't have those paths on my Computer. I decided to run the script regardless to see what it output and another common error is I don't have and assemblies relating the SharePoint I'm not sure where to get these .dlls or assemblies to make use of the attempts. I didn't make this SharePoint I just was given access to make changes and work with the data present.

Comment: If you have access to any of your SharePoint farm you will find them on the same path as it appears in the script. Another way to get them is getting the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll/) and then use them from that location.

Answer (score 0):

Both CSOM and PowerShell command can be used to delete items in SharePoint list items. Here are some scripts you can have a try in your environment.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17895.powershell-script-to-delete-items-from-sharepoint-list.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ahmedamin/2017/08/03/bulk-delete-sharepoint-items-in-a-large-list-using-powershell/